# How to select the user with max count by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns

UserID, Count, Date

I'd like to be able to select the userid with the highest count for each date.

I've tried a few different variations of queries with inline select statements but none have worked 100%, and I'm not too fond of having a select with three inline selects.

Is doing inline selects the only way to go without using temp tables?  Whats the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1

Comment: Is the Date column a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`? If the latter does it have a time component?

Comment: It is a DateTime, but I am only interested in grouping by the Date portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Date] is in fact a [Date] column with no time component:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT [Date], [Count], UserID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Count] DESC)
    FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT [Date], [Count], UserID
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [Date];
```

If `[Date]` is a `DATETIME` column with a time component, then:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [Date]), '19000101'), 
    [Count], UserID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [Date]), '19000101')
       ORDER BY [Count] DESC)
    FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT [Date], [Count], UserID
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [Date];
```

If you want to pick a specific row in the event of a tie, you can add a tie-breaker to the `ORDER BY` within the over. If you want to include multiple rows in the case of ties, you can try changing `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will give you multiple records if there is a tie in Count but should work.

```
SELECT a.Date, a.UserId, a.[Count]
FROM yourTable a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX([Count]) as [Count], Date
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY Date
) b ON a.[Count] = b.[Count] AND a.Date = b.Date
ORDER BY a.Date
```

Comment: You may need to perform some conversion and/or range checking on the dates, unless it really is a `DATE` column with no time.

Comment: Good point, this solution assumes no time component in the date column

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
  SELECT Date
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY Date
) t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    UserID, Count, Date
  FROM atable
  WHERE Date = t.Date
  ORDER BY Count DESC
) x
```

If `Date` is `datetime` type and can have a non-zero time component, change the `t` table like this:

```
…
FROM (
  SELECT Date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date), 0)
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date), 0)
) t
…
```

References:

- [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)
- [Using APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for SQL 2k5

```
select UserID, Count, Date
from tb
where Rank() over (partition by Date order by Count DESC, UserID DESC) = 1
```

Comment: +1 for the ranking functions - much faster than correlated subqueries.

Comment: that doesn't actually work... "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."; you'll still have to use a derived table

Comment: ...or a common table expression. And while we're on this, I prefer to use `ROW_NUMBER` because there's no potential for ties.

Comment: And this is not true that "ranking functions - much faster than correlated subqueries" I've seen set ups when they are not.

Comment: If you have a handful of results being returned, then correlated subqueries are probably faster (the performance penalty for such a small number of rebinds on the underlying operators would be less than ranking the entire result set), but if you're not filtering your result set and using the entire table then the ranking functions should prove to be much faster over time.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: *'I prefer to use `ROW_NUMBER` because there's no potential for ties.'* – It is possible that ties *must* be accounted in this particular case.

Comment: It was a general comment, I use it on data I don't expect to have ties because it's one less thing to worry about. And the wording "I'd like to be able to select the userid with the highest count for each date" suggests "For each date, I'd like 1 userid"